# Rails migrations pending, replacing database file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through Ruby on Rails tutorial.

I created application, model, controller. I used `rake db:migrate`, and, as the book stated - replaced file `development.sqlite3` in `db` directory with the one they provided.

Now, when I want to see my site, I get an error: Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

When I run it, I receive message: can't be done, table ads already exists. What should I do?

Comment: Could you post a link of said tutorial? I'm surprised they make you replace your sqlite database with theirs.

Comment: try `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=development`

Answer (score 0):

Table ads are already there on your db and in pending migration again creae ads table so you got the error.

you can try.

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=development
```

It  `does db:drop, db:setup`

Comment: thank you, the problem is when I reset, it doesn't solve my problem. File goes back to its original size and site won't load any date from database.

Comment: no you do not do again and again just once before start to construct the db with proper runn of migrations